# How ADT Determines that this is a Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have written a class following some Android Tutorials. The class is stored as 
"ToDoList\src\com.example.todolist\ToDoListItemView.java"

```
package com.example.todolist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ToDoListItemView extends TextView{

private Paint marginPaint,linePaint;
private int paperColor;
private float margin;

public ToDoListItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public ToDoListItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public ToDoListItemView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    Resources myResources = getResources();

    //Create the paint resources to be used in the onDraw method
    marginPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    marginPaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.notepad_margin));
    linePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    linePaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.notepad_lines));

    //Get paper background color and margin width
    paperColor = myResources.getColor(R.color.notepad_paper);
    margin = myResources.getDimension(R.dimen.notepad_margin);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(paperColor);

    //Draw ruled lines
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, getMeasuredHeight(), linePaint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), linePaint);

    //Draw margin
    canvas.drawLine(margin, 0, margin, getMeasuredHeight(), marginPaint);

    //Move text across from the margin
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(margin, 0);

    //Render
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

}

When I create a new layout in 
"ToDoList\res\layout"
with any name, it I type "com.", it automatically recommends me the path
"com.example.todolist.ToDoListItemView"
I would like to know that what distinguishing feature in my "ToDoListItemView.java" made eclipse believe that it is a layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It recommends `ToDoListItemView` because it's a `CustomView`.

Eclipse recognizes that your class `ToDoListItemView` is derived from `TextView` which is **derived from** `View`.

All classes extending `View` can be used in a layout.

If your class does not in some way extend `View`, it cannot be placed into a layout.

Comment: Hey its phillip again...Hiii :)

Comment: Ok...I tried with list view, it worked. So, yes...you are right. Thank You v much